# Inject local formulae into brew

Tags: macos, homebrew, dependency-management

I've got a project with complicated dependencies, and I'd like to make it easier for other developers to grab them. I've got a `Capfile`, `Gemfile`, `Guardfile`, `Procfile`, and `Rakefile`, so I thought... why not a `Brewfile` to manage system-level package dependencies for mac developers who clone the project?

My hope is to make a local formula that is just a list of dependencies, something like:

```
# Brewfile
require 'formula'

class DeveloperProject < Formula
  depends_on 'mongodb'
  depends_on 'postgresql'
  depends_on 'solr'
  depends_on 'phantomjs'
end
```

Developers checking out the repo for the first time could just `brew install developer_project`, and as the dependencies change, they could `brew update developer_project`.

The problem is, my brew-fu isn't good enough to figure out how to get brew to recognize this formula without creating an entire repository for it somewhere.

At first I thought I could try to pass in the file path somehow:

```
brew install /Users/me/Projects/DeveloperProject/Brewfile
```

Then I thought I might be able to simulate a tap without necessarily hosting an actual repo, for proper alternate-formula-source management:

```
mkdir -c /usr/local/Library/Taps/local-tap/Formula/
ln -s \
  /Users/me/Projects/DeveloperProject/Brewfile \
  /usr/local/Library/Taps/local-tap/Formula/developer_project.rb
brew install developer_project
```

Then I thought I could symlink it into my formulae, although it would make for brittle `brew update`s:

```
ln -s \
  /Users/me/Projects/DeveloperProject/Brewfile \
  /usr/local/Library/Formula/developer_project.rb
brew install developer_project
```

I couldn't find a way to make any of these work, and each approach felt increasingly hacky. Is there a way to do this with brew without quacking like a repository? Otherwise, is there a way to successfully quack like a remote formula source? Am I missing an already-existing way to make a brew manifest for a project?

Comment: TLDR, is there a way to make a local brew formula that can be used as a dependency manifest like a `Gemfile` for situations that are way too simple to merit a full-blown formula repository somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I'm not the first with [this idea](https://github.com/andrew/brewdler)! Brewdler doesn't support specific taps or anything, but it'll work for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can install an arbitrary formula using a URL, though not a file name. So if you turn the path in that `brew install /Users/me/...` command in to a `file://` URL, you can probably get it to work simply without having to maintain a repo or tap or anything like that.

Note that to get it to automatically update stuff, you'll need to explicitly put a version number inside your formula, and bump it each time your dependencies change.

Comment: That's a pretty cool idea! I'll have to play around with it and see if it works.